# Android: Launch Chrome in background programmatically

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit, mobile-webkit

How can we launch **Chrome** in background in Android *pragmatically* without notifying user? We have web version of our product which is responsive and also designed to handle mobile resolutions and it best works on chrome.

[Android app launch on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445022/android-app-launch-on-background)

I have written a simple app which uses android native webkit to render website on mobile. Can I use Chrome services/engine as a webkit to render my website? Does android Chrome expose such methods?

I know that from **Kitkat** onward, webkit used by Android is based on Chrome engine. How to handle older versions of android for such requirements? **And what if Chrome is not installed on device?**

Thanks